# How to append string before and after a line using sed

Tags: text-processing

I have lines form a command output as given below.

```
service:clus1-svr          clus1-node2                      started    [Z]
service:clus1-svr          clus1-node2                      started
```

I want to add string before and after the line which indicate [Z] only. So the result may come as:

```
<font>service:clus1-svr          clus1-node2                      started    [Z]</font>
```

Can anyone please help me to do this. Your help greatly appreciated.

i tried below, but that changes all the line from the output

```
sed -i "s/.*/<font color="red">&<\/font>/"
```

Comment: Are the separators spaces or tabs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were pretty close with your attempt; all you needed to do was to narrow down the execution of the substitution only to lines containing `[Z]` at the end:

```
sed -i '/\[Z\]$/ s/.*/<font>&<\/font>/' infile
```

However, here's another `awk` solution:

```
awk '$4=="[Z]" {printf("%s%s%s\n", "<font>", $0, "</font>"); next} {print}' infile
```

- `$4=="[Z]"`: pattern; if the 4th field of the currently processed record is `[Z]`, executes the following action; otherwise, it skips to the next pattern / action;
- `printf("%s%s%s\n", "<font>", $0, "</font>")`: prints `<font>`, the currently processed record and `</font>` as strings followed by a newline;
- `next`: skips to the next record;
- `print`: prints the currently processed record followed by a newline;

Sample output:

```
user@debian ~ % cat infile
service:clus1-svr          clus1-node2                      started    [Z]
service:clus1-svr          clus1-node2                      started
user@debian ~ % awk '$4=="[Z]" {printf("%s%s%s\n", "<font>", $0, "</font>"); next} {print}' infile
<font>service:clus1-svr          clus1-node2                      started    [Z]</font>
service:clus1-svr          clus1-node2                      started
```

Comment: Thank you very much Kos, sed -i '/\[Z\]$/ s/.*/<font>&<\/font>/' infile resolved the query i have in a pretty cool manner. I have also tried awk '$4=="[Z]" {printf("%s%s%s\n", "<font>", $0, "</font>"); next} {print}' infile. Awsome, i am happy with this too. Thank you very very much

Answer (score 4):

You can use this :

```
sed -n '/\[Z\]$/ s/^/<font>/;/\[Z\]$/ s/$/<\/font>/p' file.txt
```

As you will use it over STDOUT of another command, so use it as e.g. :

```
some command | sed -n '/\[Z\]$/ s/^/<font>/;/\[Z\]$/ s/$/<\/font>/p'
```

It basically has two parts :

- `/\[Z\]$/ s/^/<font>/` will match the line that has `[Z]` at last, then will add `<font>` at the start of the line by `s/^/<font>/`
- `/\[Z\]$/ s/$/<\/font>/` will match `[Z]` at the end of the line and then will add `</font>` at the end of the line using `/$/<\/font>/`.

Example :

```
$ cat file.txt 
service:clus1-svr          clus1-node2                      started    [Z]
service:clus1-svr          clus1-node2                      started

$ sed -n '/\[Z\]$/ s/^/<font>/;/\[Z\]$/ s/$/<\/font>/p' file.txt 
<font>service:clus1-svr          clus1-node2                      started    [Z]</font>
```

As @glennjackman has pointed out you can also use a grouping construct to do all the replacements for a single match :

```
$ sed -n '/\[Z\]$/ { s/^/<font>/; s/$/<\/font>/p }' file.txt 
<font>service:clus1-svr          clus1-node2                      started    [Z]</font>
```

---

How about a `bash` solution :

```
while IFS= read -r line; do [[ $line =~ \[Z\]$ ]] && echo "<font>${line}</font>"; done <file.txt
```

You can use it as :

```
some command | while IFS= read -r line; do [[ $line =~ \[Z\]$ ]] && echo "<font>${line}</font>"; done
```

This uses the same logic as the `sed` one. If the line ends with `[Z]` (`[[ $line =~ \[Z\]$ ]]`), then the line is printed in desired format.

Example :

```
$ while IFS= read -r line; do [[ $line =~ \[Z\]$ ]] && echo "<font>${line}</font>"; done <file.txt 
<font>service:clus1-svr          clus1-node2                      started    [Z]</font>
```

Comment: sed has a grouping construct, so you can write `sed '/\[Z\]/ { s/^/<font>; s,$,</font>, }`

Comment: @glennjackman Thanks..AFAIK thats a GNU entension, right ?

Comment: Also I think OP were close with their attempt: `sed -i '/\[Z\]$/ s/.*/<font>&<\/font>/' infile`

Comment: @kos Yeah, your modification is on the money....

Comment: @kos Perhaps you should add that as an answer, i totally overlooked OP's solution so your's one would give him a better idea i guess..i would love to give an upvote on that :)

Comment: I added an `awk` solution and explained that on a side note :)

Comment: @kos done.... :)

Comment: Thank you guys. He he these looks very good and i really appreciate your help. You guys helped me so quickly.

Answer (score 1):

`Awk` version.

Tested with the OP's example pasted twice into the same file, so as you can see it edits those two lines which have `[Z]`, and two which don't contain it

```
  $ awk ' {if ($0~/\[Z\]/)  print "<font>"$0"</font>";else print}' testfile.txt                                                                   
<font>service:clus1-svr          clus1-node2                      started    [Z]</font>
service:clus1-svr          clus1-node2                      started
<font>service:clus1-svr          clus1-node2                      started    [Z]</font>
service:clus1-svr          clus1-node2                      started
```

To output the edits to the file, use the following construct:

`awk ' {if ($0~/\[Z\]/)  print "<font>"$0"</font>";else print}' testfile.txt > /tmp/tmp.txt && cat /tmp/tmp.txt > testfile.txt`

Comment: I like this solution more than my solution actually. I forgot that you can concatenate strings that way with `print`

Comment: Yes. This is absolutely great. Thank you Serg. I am in trouble as i am not able to select you all as winner :( Yes you guys rocks!